# Host heroku changes with each code loaded or when reloading the service

Tags: heroku, dns, host, heroku-cli, heroku-ci

I have an application on heroku and I try to connect and fetch information from a remote database. I need to give permission on that remote database, informing the host, but every time I load new code in the heroku app, with heroku cli, or when it goes down and restarts the service, it changes the host origin in the request as described below :

```
Access denied for user 'bpgea023_teste'@'ec2-44-203-99-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

Informing the host in this snippet, `ec2-44-203-99-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

I don't use paid Dyno, and I didn't do any DNS configuration, I expected the source host to be the same auto-generated one, like `app-test.herokuapp.com`

Have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the % wildcard possibility, the solution is `%.amazonaws.com`, putting that as permissive host.